# Bootstrap datetimepicker multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Im using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Having

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({locale: 'sv'});
```

works fine.

The html then look like this:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

However, if I change the html so the "datetimepicker1" becomes a class instead of an id, like this:

```
<div class='input-group date' class='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

and after that I change javascript like this:

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'sv'
});
```

Then nothing happens. The calender doesnt show up. I cannot see any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.datetimepicker1').each(function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({locale: 'sv'});
});
```

EDIT:

Your code is wrong you declared `class` attribute twice it should be:

```
       <div class='input-group date datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: didnt help. still nothing showing up. no info in console.

Comment: This is wrong: `<div class='input-group date' class='datetimepicker1'>` it should be  `<div class='input-group date datetimepicker1'>`

Comment: you need to add class only once